# How to remove orphaned "ATM ELAN Connection" from Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

Although there are no ATM or similar adapters into a PC running Windows 2003 server, two connections named "ATM ELAN Connection" appear in the Network Connections.
The related device appears in the Device Manager as "ATM Emulated LAN".

There's no way to remove them:
- Within the Device Manager, an error is thrown: "Failed to uninstall the device. The device may be required to boot up the computer" (tried also the removal booting in Safe Mode, same error)
- Within the Control Panel->Network connections: "The connection you selected cannot be deleted"

Any idea?

Comment: Could be due to an old PCI DSL adapter installed long time a go. Unsure. There may be some garbage left in the registry..... how to safely remove from the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have manually and CAREFULLY Removed all instances associated to the adapter in the registry and rebooted!
After the reboot the adapter was disappeared from the network connections (finally) but still showing in the Device manager under the hidden devices; selected and deleted; little wait and VOILA' :-)
**Do not attempt to do so unless you clearly know what you're doing. Bad editing can bring the machine to unrecoverable\unstable mode**

EDIT:

How to:

- Backup your registry
- In the registry navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}**
- Within the key above inspect each subkey (0000,0001, etc) looking for the adapter description in the **Connection** key (**Name** string); you will delete the whole key once the steps below are taken;
- Copy the guid contained in the string **pnpInstanceId**
- Delete the whole subkey (000x, etc) as stated before
- Delete each reference to the annotated guid found in the registry, be careful particularly when editing multi-line strings
- Reboot
- Once rebooted, look into the Device Manager, enabling hidden devices and delete the orphaned adpaters, if any left
- You're done